# How to add CSS StyleClass when instantiating object, instead of object.addStyleClass("myStyle")

Tags: css, sapui5

I work with SAPUI5, and I want to add a style to an object as soon as I instantiate it. For example, I want to add styleclass 'foo' to my label inside my panel.

What I want to do, but doesn't work:

```
var oPanel = new sap.m.Panel({
 content: new sap.m.Label({
 text: "Hello",
 styleClass: "foo"
 })
});
```

What I don't want to do, but does work:

```
var oLabel = new sap.m.Label({
text: "Hello"
});
oLabel.addStyleClass("foo");

var oPanel = new sap.m.Panel({
content: oLabel
});
```

Comment: You´re right, it is a missing feature. Only XML Views support it. However, what´s the reason you don´t want to call `addStyleClass()`? Since the rendering won´t be triggered at that moment it makes no difference. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/29508061/1969374.

Comment: Another plus in favor of using XMLViews ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the replies, and haha Qualiture :) I only want it to make my code more concise and readable for colleagues. Thank you for the answer and reference Tim, I looked but didn't find it.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I don't think it is explicitly mentioned somewhere (which is an omission IMO) but at https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/guide/b564935324f449209354c7e2f9903f22.html there is a reference to the `class` property in an XML control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's another option based on method chaining which does not require a dedicated variable for the inner elements (which I guess is the reason why you do not like the 2nd variant in your question):

```
var oPanel = new sap.m.Panel({
   content: new sap.m.Label({ text: "Hello" }).addStyleClass("foo")
});
```

Comment: I think this is the most elegant solution with regards to readability

Answer (score 1):

you can even write your own custom classes where the style class is an aggregation. I am not sure as yet how this can be done but I was able to write custom labels with 'color' aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to return your control instances, and inside of it make use of the addStyleClass method, and others you would like

```
function getControlInstance(FnClass, sId, mSettings) {
    mSettings = mSettings || {};
    if (typeof sId !== "string") {
        mSettings = sId;
        sId = null;
    }
    var oControl = new FnClass(sId, mSettings);
    if (mSettings.styleClass) {
        mSettings.styleClass = mSettings.styleClass instanceof Array ? mSettings.styleClass : [mSettings.styleClass];
        mSettings.styleClass.forEach(function (sClass) {
            oControl.addStyleClass(sClass);
        });
    }
    return oControl;
}
```

Use like this

```
var a = getControlInstance(sap.m.HBox, {
    styleClass: "test",
    id: "asdoiasd",
    items: [
        new getControlInstance(sap.m.Text, {
            styleClass: "test",
            text: "Testing"
        })
    ]
})
```