# Bind CSS class of a UI5 control programatically to a model value

Tags: sapui5

Is there a way to bind the class attribute of a ui5-input-template inside a `sap.ui.table.Table` to a model value?

What I tried so far is:

```js
[
  {
    label: 'arow',
    disabled: true,
    class: 'myClass1',
    data: [
      {
        value: 'rowVal1'
      }
    ]
  },
  // ...
]
```

and

```js
myTable.bindColumns("/columns", function (index: string, context: any) {
  let indParts: string[] = index.split("-");
  let ind = +indParts[indParts.length - 1];
  var colLabel = context.getProperty().label;
  let template = new sap.m.Input({
    value: `{data/${ind}/value}`,
    class: '{= ${class} }',
    enabled: '{= !${disabled} && !${data/' + ind + '/disabled} }',
  });
  // template.addStyleClass('{class}');
  // template.setClass('{class}');
  let column =  new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: colLabel,
    width: `{width}`,
    template: template,
  });
  return column;
});
myTable.bindRows("/rows");
```

It seems as if I cannot use the model binding here, only add static class values when I create the template. Is this right?

Comment: `class` is not bindable because it's not even a valid property of any ManagedObject. You'd have to extend the Input control with an additional control property (e.g. named `"styleClass"`) and then make it bindable

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann, thanks for the explanation. I thought because I used it in my xml view on input elements before I could use it here too. Too bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, one of the solutions is to enhance the control's set of properties with your own property to allow binding the style class.

Here is a working sample: [https://embed.plnkr.co/ik9PIdHKvK8udpQt](https://embed.plnkr.co/ik9PIdHKvK8udpQt?show=index.html,control%2FInput.js,preview&autoCloseSidebar)

And here a snippet from the control extension:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/m/Input",
  "sap/m/InputRenderer",
], function(Input, InputRenderer) {
  "use strict";

  return Input.extend("demo.control.Input", {
    metadata: {
      properties: {
        "styleClass": {
          type: "string",
          defaultValue: null,
          bindable: true,
        }
      }
    },

    renderer: { // will be merged with the parent renderer (InputRenderer)
      apiVersion: 2, // enabling semantic rendering (aka. DOM-patching)
      // Implement the hook method from the parent renderer
      addOuterClasses: function (oRenderManager, oInput) {
        InputRenderer.addOuterClasses.apply(this, arguments);
        oRenderManager
          .class("demoControlInput") // Standard CSS class of demo.control.Input
          .class(oInput.getStyleClass()); // Custom CSS class defined by application
      },
    },

  });
});
```

As documented in the topic [**Extending Input Rendering**](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/bcee26a4801748f39bf5698d83d903aa), some base controls allow overwriting existing methods from the renderer. If you look at the `sap.m.InputRenderer`, for example, you can see that the renderer provides multiple hooks to be overwritten by subclasses such as the [`addOuterClasses`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.InputRenderer#methods/sap.m.InputRenderer.addOuterClasses).

And since `styleClass` in our customer control is a valid `ManagedObject` property, binding in JavaScript ("programmatically") also works:

```js
new Input({ // required from "demo/control/Input"
  // ...,
  styleClass: "{= ${class}}"
});
```