# Extending a control reusing its own original renderer

Tags: controls, sapui5, renderer

I need a custom control in my app composed by a ColumnListItem followed by a (custom) progressbar spanning all the ColumnListItem width.
I tried extending a `sap/m/ColumnListItem` adding a new custom aggregation `progress` and leveraging its original `renderer` as follows:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/m/ColumnListItem",
  "sap/m/ColumnListItemRenderer"
], function (ColumnListItem, ColumnListItemRenderer) {
  "use strict";
  return ColumnListItem.extend("my.package.MyColumListItem", {
    metadata: {
      aggregations: {
        "progress": {
          type: "my.package.MyShadowBar",
          multiple: false
        }
      }
    },
    renderer: {
      apiVersion: 2,
      render: function (oRm, oCLI) {
        ColumnListItemRenderer.render.apply(this, arguments);
        oRm.openStart("div").style("width", "100vw").openEnd();
        oRm.renderControl(oCLI.getAggregation("progress"));
        oRm.close("div");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, this works only at the first rendering: if I navigate elsewhere and then came back, all progressbars are rendered on top of the page and all the ColumnListItems are stacked at the bottom.
I'm using SAPUI5 version 1.84.xx.
I don't really understand how to implement the renderer correctly so any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241424/discussion-between-cmdd-and-boghyon-hoffmann).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAPUI5 technically allows overwriting existing methods from the respective `*Renderer` module of the parent control. Make sure to overwrite only those methods with the `@protected`/`@public` JSDoc tag **in addition to automated tests** for your app to stay compatible with future UI5 releases. Here is an example how the `InputRenderer` was extended by overwriting the protected `addOuterClasses` method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67919830/5846045.

It's also possible to extend the parent `*Renderer` within an *external* renderer as explained by the [API reference `Renderer.extend`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.Renderer#methods/sap.ui.core.Renderer.extend). The extension definition stays same.

---

In your case, the requirement sounds like it could be achieved without extending the `sap.m.ColumnListItem`. Either way, here is a [minimal sample that showcases both approaches](https://embed.plnkr.co/MSOzEIVX0uJDulDN?show=control%2FColumnListProgressItem.js,control%2FColumnListProgressItemRenderer.js,preview): rendering the progress bar via the extended item renderer, and via the standard popin approach without any extension.